# Configurable background color when cropping to larger dimensions

Tags: php, colors, background, crop

When I crop the image with one or both dimensions exceeding the source dimensions, the excess area  is rendered in black.

I try to change black in white, but it replace also the black inside the image.

I searched among the various questions and tried many codes but I have not found anything that solves the problem without generate other.

**I want white only in the excess area, not inside the image.**

Could you help me? This is my code

```html
function crop($x, $y, $width, $height) 
{
if(!$this->error) 
{
$tmpimage = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
      
imagecopyresampled($tmpimage, $this->img, 0, 0, $x, $y,
$width, $height, $width, $height);
         
$color = imagecolorallocate($tmpimage, 255, 255, 255);


imagefill($tmpimage, 0, 0, $color);


imagedestroy($this->img);
$this->img = $tmpimage;
$this->y = $height;
$this->x = $width;
}
}
```